# Getting "Failed to upload file" error in DMS task

Tags: amazon-web-services, dms

I see below error in cloudwatch logs while running the DMS task. MYSQL RDS is the source endpoint and Redshift is the target endpoint:

> Error - "Failed to upload file '/rdsdbdata/data/tasks/FIIXC322HNNOONDMJ47ZUVYIQPB2KMR7LOFQKFA/cloud/41/LOAD00000001.gzip' to bucket 'dms-zcajgkjte5t4err3ijcfq5colwj27lwfjyreywq' as 'redshift-LW75HFVWQABDNQH4FNEWVIADLHQOPAWSOG7CVKY/FIIXC322HNNOONDMJ47ZUVYIQPB2KMR7LOFQKFA/41/LOAD00000001.csv', status = 4 (FAILED) [1001705]  (transfer_client.cpp:514)"

Comment: Hi All, this is the error which i'm getting now-

Comment: Failed to list bucket 'dms-zcajgkjte5t4err3ijcfq5colwj27lwfjyreywq': error code <>: curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached [1001713]  (s3_dir_actions.cpp:105)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: After more trial and error than I would like to admit:
This pointed me into the correct direction -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_VPC_Endpoints.html

For me, the selected routing table for the VPC endpoint did not include any table with a connected internet gateway, which caused the "Failed to upload file" error because there was obviously no route to the S3 bucket…

Here are some general tips, if you end up in a similar situation:

- Make sure you check your VPC endpoint configuration!
- Make sure the related roles have all the required permissions (dms-access-for-endpoint, dms-access-for-tasks and dms-vpc-role)
- Check the following cases: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-task-successful-no-data-s3
- You can turn on the S3 access logs.(If you turn them on and no logs appear, it is probably a network configuration problem)

Hope this helps, good luck!